# Variable delay triggering of a task with freeRtos

Tags: delay, freertos

Hy,

in my application based on FreeRTOS I receive a message from the EMAC,

the payload contains an integer representing a time in ms,

if the payload is 5 it means I've to do something after 5ms,

instead if the payload is 10 it means I've to do something after 10ms, and so on,

my question is about the best way to implement this variable triggering of a task using freeRTOS on TMDX570LC43HDK?

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

How precise do you need the timing to be? You could use a FreeRTOS timer to trigger a task, however for example, 5ms might be anywhere from just over 4ms to 5ms as its based on the rtos tick.

If you need a precise time use a hardware timer to trigger an interrupt which can trigger a task.

For either method you can use task notifications.